Sequential numbering with a prefix by grouped attributes
I need to label different groups of attributes sequentially. So for example I may have attributes with IDs A,B and C and I need to be able to pick out the 'A' group and number them with the same prefix. For example:
XYZ-A-001, XYZ-A-002, XYZ-A-003...

Once I have an expression for this I can pick out and do the same for the 'B' and 'C' groups
XYZ-B-001, XYZ-B-002, XYZ-B-003...
XYZ-C-001, XYZ-C-002, XYZ-C-003...


see this solution with is more or less the same: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/463742/87346
